# Get list with unique sub-lists

Tags: scala

I have a list of lists and I want to get the list with only unique sub-lists. For instance, this input:

```
List((123,List(List(xxx, abc),List(xxx,abc),List(yyy,abc))),
     (333,List(List(xxx, abc),List(yyy,abc),List(yyy,abc))))
```

should be converted into:

```
List((123,List(List(xxx,abc),List(yyy,abc))),
     (333,List(List(xxx, abc),List(yyy,abc))))
```

I tried this:

```
val unique = input.map(list => (list._1, list._2.distinct))
```

but it does not do the expected trick. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map and do `distinct` on the inner list.

```
mainList.map { case (a, list) => a -> list.distinct }
```

As your `mainList` consists of tuples, you can also use the tuple `_2` to get the list in the tuple.

```
mainList.map(pair => pair._1 -> pair._2.distinct)
```

`distinct` will take care of keeping only the unique elements in the list.